# Back navigation handling for web app

Tags: react.js, jsx, user-interface

I need to implement back navigation handling on multiple pages of my react application. Currently I have added an alert on when the browser back button is clicked. I would like to optimize my code and make it better. I feel there can be a better way to add back handling to web apps in react. Any help suggestion or better solution is much appreciated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const BackButtonListener = () => {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
    window.addEventListener("popstate", function () {
      setPressed(true);

      window.history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
    });
  }, []);
  return pressed ? alert("Home: Back button pressed") : null;
};

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BackButtonListener />
      <h1>This is the home page</h1>
      <Link to="about">About Us</Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```